# Find a norm that is not equivalent to Sup Norm for $C(X)$ where $X$ is compact

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric set that is compact and $C(X)$ is the set of all continuous functions from $X\to \mathbb{C}$. If $X$ is infinite, I want to find a norm for $C(X)$ that is not equivalent to $$\Vert f \Vert = sup_{x\in X}f(x)$$
I first thought of $\Vert f \Vert_p=(\int_a^b \vert f \vert^p)^\frac{1}{p}$ that is a norm on $C([a,b])$. But is $X$ of the form $[a,b]$?
I'm stuck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you precise what $X$ is? Is it a subset of a *known space*? Is it measurable?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I's metric and it's compact

Comment: Using integrals requires extra structure that you do not have. Take $\Vert f \Vert = \sup_{x\in X}|f(x)g(x)|$, where $g(x)$ is some continuous function that vanishes at a single point on $X$. For example, $g(x):=\textrm{dist}(x,x_0)$.

Comment: @Conifold Would you please answer with more detail?

Answer (score 3):

Since $X$ is  a compact metric space it is separable. Let $(x_n)$ be a countably infinite dense set in it. Define $\|f\|' =\sum \frac {|f(x_n)|} {2^{n}}$. If this is equivalent to sup norm the there is a finite constant $C$ such that $|f(x)| \leq C\sum \frac {|f(x_n)|} {2^{n}}$. There is a  a function $f \in C(X)$ such that $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$ and, $\|f\|_{\infty}=1$ and   $f(x_i)=0$ for $1\leq i \leq N$. We get $1 \leq C\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty} \frac1 {2^{n}}$ which is a contradiction if $N$ is large enough.

Comment: Isn't there any simpler norm?

Comment: The example by Canifold works but that also requires a proof for non-equivalence of the norms. Note that the fact that $X$ is not finite has to be used.

Comment: How to show that the example by Conifold works?

Comment: Because I can't understand some parts of your answer. Why do we need the separability of $X$ and how did you define $(x_n)$. Thank you in advance for explaining in more detail.

Comment: If $\|f\|'=0$ then $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n$ and this implies $f\equiv 0$. This is where we have to take a dense sequence $(x_n)$ and not just any infinite subset.  @James